# Fire and forget for HTTP in Java

Tags: java, httprequest, httpclient, analytics, httpresponse

We're implementing our own analytics for that we've exposed a web service which needs to be invoked which will capture the data in our DB.

The problem is that as this is analytics we would be making lot of calls (like for every page load, call after each js, CSS loads etc...) so there'll be many many such calls. So I don want the server to be loaded with lots of requests to be more precise pending for response. Because the response we get back will hardly be of any use to us.

So is there any way to just fire the web service request and forget that I've fired it?

I understand that every HTTP request will have as response as well.

So one thing that ticked my mind was what if we make the request timeout to zero second? But I'm pretty not sure if this is the right way of doing this.

Please provide me with more suggestions

Comment: instead of making a call every time an event you want to record occurs, collect the event data and make fewer calls.

Comment: At some point you could consider UDP for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might find following `AsyncRequestDemo.java` useful:

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import org.apache.http.client.fluent.Async;
import org.apache.http.client.fluent.Content;
import org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
import org.apache.http.concurrent.FutureCallback;

/**
 * Following libraries have been used:
 * 
 * 1) httpcore-4.4.5.jar
 * 2) httpclient-4.5.2.jar
 * 3) commons-logging-1.2.jar
 * 4) fluent-hc-4.5.2.jar     * 
 *
 */

public class AsyncRequestDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URIBuilder urlBuilder = new URIBuilder()
                               .setScheme("http")
                               .setHost("stackoverflow.com")
                               .setPath("/questions/38277471/fire-and-forget-for-http-in-java");

    final int nThreads = 3; // no. of threads in the pool
    final int timeout = 0; // connection time out in milliseconds

    URI uri = null;
    try {
        uri = urlBuilder.build();
    } catch (URISyntaxException use) {
        use.printStackTrace();
    }

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);
    Async async = Async.newInstance().use(executorService);
    final Request request = Request.Get(uri).connectTimeout(timeout);

        Future<Content> future = async.execute(request, new FutureCallback<Content>() {
            public void failed(final Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Request failed: " + request);
                System.exit(1);
            }

            public void completed(final Content content) {
                System.out.println("Request completed: " + request);
                System.out.println(content.asString());
                System.exit(0);
            }

            public void cancelled() {
            }
        });

        System.out.println("Request submitted");

    }

}
```

Comment: this solution is better than what I thought but, still there'll be still 12(or whatever threadpool size) threads. Problem here is we R using it for analytics so we need to serve lot of requests. Can we think of something else ? May be threadpool with some size n setting network time-out to zero?

Comment: Hi @GokulKulkarni the two aspects i) `threadpool with some size n` and ii) `network time-out` have incorporated in the answer. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I used this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

  URL url = new URL(YOUR_URL_PATH, "UTF-8")); 
               ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1); 
               Future<HttpResponse> response = executor.submit(new HttpRequest(url));
               executor.shutdown();
```

for HttpRequest,HttpResponse

```
public class HttpRequest implements Callable<HttpResponse> {
        private URL url;

        public HttpRequest(URL url) {
            this.url = url;
        }

        @Override
        public HttpResponse call() throws Exception {
            return new HttpResponse(url.openStream());
        }
}

public class HttpResponse {
     private InputStream body;

        public HttpResponse(InputStream body) {
            this.body = body;
        }

        public InputStream getBody() {
            return body;
        }
}
```

that is.

Comment: In this method we close the executor but I assume that the thread will still wait for the response as HTTP is designed to do that. Below are two links in order which will help understand the basics: 
1. https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/xml-dist-app/2006Jan/0061.html
2. https://systembash.com/a-simple-java-udp-server-and-udp-client/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could initiate the request and break the connection without waiting for a response... **But** you probably don't want to do that.  The overhead of the server-side having to deal with ungracefully broken connections will far outweigh letting it proceed with returning a response.

A better approach to solving this kind of performance problem in a Java servlet would bet to shove all the data from the requests into a queue, respond immediately, and have one or more worker threads pick up items out of the queue for processing (such as writing it into a database).

Comment: 'The overhead ... will far outweigh' why? How can not sending data over the wire be worse than sending data over the wire.

Comment: Because Java is going to throw an exception, generate a stack trace, etc... which will have to be handled.  That gets expensive if the concern is performance.  The connection/handshakes have already been established, so completing the response (even an empty one) is safer than breaking the connection.  btw - I didn't say you couldn't do it.  I said you probably don't want to.